# changin modalPresentationStyle after rotaiting

Tags: ipad, rotation, presentmodalviewcontroller

I need help in problem. I want to change modalPresentationStyle dynamicaly when it open, after rotating event. 
I write this for create modalView

```
 ZUITableViewController *ivc = [[ZUITableViewController alloc] init];
    ivc.delegate = self;
    _modalIsShowing = TRUE;
    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ivc];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
    {
        nc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
        nc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    }
    else{
        nc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    }
    [self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];
    [ivc release];
    [nc release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrap the if statement `UIModalPresentationPageSheet` behaves properly to start with.

```
ZUITableViewController *ivc = [[ZUITableViewController alloc] init];
ivc.delegate = self;
_modalIsShowing = TRUE;
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ivc];
nc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];
[ivc release];
[nc release];
```